Completeness of the atomic Hardy space $H^{p,q}(X)$ on spaces of homogeneous type
I have a problem with the following fact: the article by Coifman and Weiss, "Extensions of Hardy spaces and their use in analysis" https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-83/issue-4/Extensions-of-Hardy-spaces-and-their-use-in-analysis/bams/1183538894.full, states that the atomic Hardy space
$H^{p,q}(X)$ on a space of homogeneous type is a quasi-normed, metric, and complete space. I have been able to demonstrate everything except completeness. How could I prove it?
